# awk - send variable to .awk script and use as conditional

Tags: variables, awk, conditional-statements

I want to send a variable to my external .awk script to use as a conditional. The following script is however not working.

Here first is the command:

```
awk -v myVar="optA" -f /users/test/fixit.awk /users/test/input.txt > /users/test/output.txt
```

The sample fixit.awk script is:

```
BEGIN { printf "TITLE:\nDocuments \n", myVar, FS=" "; }

if (myVar="optA")
      printf myVar
else 
      printf "OptB"
```

Can someone please help diagnose the problem?

Comment: You probably don't mean to have a comma before `FS=" "`.  Also, you probably don't even need that `FS` assignment at all, because the default input field separator is white space.

Comment: See [Assigning Variables on the Command Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Assignment-Options.html) from GNU awk documentation.  Also, reading [a nice tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) might help too.

Comment: Thanks e0k, The tutorial link is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An awk assignment is also an expression with the return value of what was assigned. If you write

```
if (myVar = "optA")
```

you actually check the return value of the assignment, `optA`, which awlays evaluates to "true". You want

```
if (myVar == "optA")
```

for comparison instead of assignment.

Also, you can't have "naked" statements like this. Your if/else clause either has to be part of the `BEGIN` block:

```
BEGIN {
    printf "TITLE:\nDocuments \n", myVar, FS=" "

    if (myVar=="optA")
          printf myVar
    else 
          printf "OptB"
}
```

to execute once, or in a separate block if it should be executed for every single line (less likely, though):

```
BEGIN { printf "TITLE:\nDocuments \n", myVar, FS=" " }

{
    if (myVar=="optA")
        printf myVar
    else 
        printf "OptB"
}
```

As an aside, the way you use `printf` doesn't make much sense: you could either do

```
print "TITLE:\nDocuments\n" myVar
```

or

```
printf "TITLE:\nDocuments\n%s\n", myVar
```

And for `printf myVar` or `printf "OptB"`, unless you explicitly don't want that newline, you can as well use `print myVar` and `print "OptB"`.

And finally, that `FS=` assignment looks a bit out of place and is probably not needed as `" "` is the default value of `FS`.

Comment: Thank you, I needed the execution blocks.